# Fetch callback block never getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In a iOS app I'm developing I'm using parse.com as my backend. SDK Version is 1.2.20.

The problems come when performing fetches like this:

```
[PFObject fetchAllIfNeededInBackground:objectsToFetch block:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        }];
    }];
```

This block never gets called, with or without error. There is no timeout and there is no way to debug or to know what is going on.

I have also tried this form:

```
    NSOperationQueue * parseQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    [parseQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [PFObject fetchAll:objectsToFetch];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];
```

I set a breakpoint on reload data and it is never hit.

"po objectsToFetch"  from the debugger console:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x11620c710>(
<Object:g06aHOTaLI:(null)> {
},
<Object:XDTcLQCegF:(null)> {
},
<Object:KCIFxCSBUw:(null)> {
},
<Object:g06aHOTaLI:(null)> {
},
<Object:0PjRyl9cC4:(null)> {
},
<Object:WjYY01c931:(null)> {
},
<Object:m9F2Dm8HhD:(null)> {
}
)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Comment: How did you determine the version of the Parse SDK you were using?

Comment: I just saw it in the name of the download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of toil, I have discovered that this problem only happens when there are duplicate objects in the array to fetch.

As you can see in the array I posted above there were in fact duplicate objects.

I would like a response from someone parse.com. is this is the expected behavior or is it a bug?

If its the expected behavior, the block should be called with an error and a message saying that duplicate objects are not allowed when performing a batch fetch.

There is nothing about this in the documentation.

If it is a bug, I would be happy to post a bug report.